# How do i access multple element (list) in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I have an example dataframe as below.

| pr_id | product | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id_234 | onion,bean | chris |
| id_34d | apple | tom |
| id_87t | plantain, potato, apple | tex |

I want to access the product column and create a new column and assign 1 if apple is in the list and 0 if not.

So i expect a result like this:

| pr_id | product | name | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id_234 | onion,bean | chris | 0 |
| id_34d | apple | tom | 1 |
| id_87t | plantain, potato, apple | tex | 1 |

I thought of something like this:

```
my_df$result <- ifelse(my_df$product == 'apple', 1,0)
```

but this only work for rows 1 and 2, but not working for last row having multiple elements.

Please how do i go with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `agrepl` which searches for approximate matches within a string. If you use `==`, you are searching for exact matching.

```r
my_df <-
  structure(
    list(
      pr_id = c("id_234", "id_34d", "id_87t"),
      product = c("onion,bean",
                  "apple", "plantain, potato, apple"),
      name = c("chris", "tom",
               "tex")
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA, -3L)
  )

my_df$result <- ifelse(agrepl('apple', my_df$product), 1,0)
```

Or a tidyverse approach

```r
library(dplyr)
my_df <- 
  my_df %>% 
  mutate(result = as.numeric(agrepl('apple', product)))

my_df      
#>    pr_id                 product  name result
#> 1 id_234              onion,bean chris      0
#> 2 id_34d                   apple   tom      1
#> 3 id_87t plantain, potato, apple   tex      1
```

Comment: thanks @P.Paccioretti, the first solution solved my problem. I will also look at the tidyverse approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With dplyr, dataframe kindly taken from p. Paccioretti
Thanks to AnilGoyal for `stringr::str_detect`

```
# construct the dataframe
pr_id = c("id_234", "id_34d", "id_87t")
product = c("onion,bean",
            "apple", "plantain, potato, apple")
name = c("chris", "tom","tex")

my_df <- data.frame(pr_id, product, name)

# check with case_when and str_detect if apple is in product
my_df <- my_df %>% 
  mutate(result = case_when(stringr::str_detect(product, "apple") ~ 1,
                            TRUE ~ 0)
         )
```

Comment: This will match complete string only.  Better use `stringr::str_detect() `

Comment: @Tarjae, the case_when approach did not assign 1 to the last row with multiple elements. P. Paccioretti solution solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Please see my update. Thanks to AnilGoyal I have adapted. Now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the str_detect option in stringr (tidyverse option).

```
my_df <- my_df %>%

  mutate(result = ifelse(str_detect(product, "apple"), 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `str_count`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  mutate(result = str_count(product, 'apple'))
```